# Do I draw opportunity attacks when my mount uses flyby?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, mounted-combat, flight

I am a forest gnome ranger under the beast master archetype. If I have a flying mount with flyby, like the pteranodon, do I still draw opportunity attacks while riding it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would say no. The PHB on page 195 specifically states:

> you don't provoke attacks of opportunity when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction.

Under the Beast Master archetype on page 93 it says:

> You can command the beast where to move on your turn (no action required).

Since the beast counts as something that isn't you, and it doesn't require your action or move, you don't provoke!

Comment: You all are forgetting page 198 of the PHB for Mounted Combat.  Observe as I edit my answer.

Comment: Beast Master Archetype works entirely different once that beast becomes a **mount** .  Once you mount the creature, you give up the forfeiting of your action to control the beast as well as telling it to move freely to, instead, follow the rules of Mounted Combat as written on page 198.

Comment: Its important to note that if your mount does provoke an opportunity attack, the attacker can choose either to target the mount or the rider. However in this case since the Pteranadon doesn't provoke an opportunity attack due to Flyby, neither can they attack you.

Comment: Here are two Sage Advices that support the statement that if the mount doesn't provoke an opportunity attack, then neither does the rider: https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/04/20/can-a-mount-disengage/ and https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/06/09/mount-disengage/

Answer (score 0):

From the Monster Manual, page 80:

> **Flyby.** The **Pteranadon** does not provoke opportunity attacks when flying past an enemy.

The key word there is the Pteranadon.  If you are using the Pteranadon as a mount, than you AND the Pteranadon draw opportunity attacks separately.  So even if the Pteranadon is free from attacks due to the above ability, the character riding the mount is not.

Pg 198 PHB

> While you are mounted you have two options.  **You** can control the mount as your turn...[It's initiative changes to yours]...it only has 3 options:  **Dash**, **Disengage** and **Dodge**, or allow it to act independently [if intelligence is high enough]...An independent mount retains it's [own] place in the initiative order and has no restrictions on the actions it can take and moves and acts as it wishes.  ***In either case, if an attack of opportunity is provoked while you are on it, the attacker can target you or the mount.***

Comment: Note that the current wording in the PHB says: "In either case, if **the mount** provokes an opportunity attack while you’re on it, the attacker can target you or the mount." Which is different from the way you quote it and seems to undercut your answer's argument.

Comment: There is nothing in these rules suggesting that the rider provokes an OA when the mount moves, only that the rider can be targeted with OA provoked from the mount. Since the mount doesn't provoke OAs in the first place (thanks flyby and/or disengage!), the rider will be safe aswell.