# What mounts are Centaurs capable of using?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, mount, centaur

While it is understood that a centaur could be used as a mount under certain conditions, such is in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139366/how-do-the-rules-work-for-a-centaur-being-a-mount), I am asking whether or not a Centaur is capable of using a mount for **itself**. Is there an contraption or creature that is capably of serving a Centaur as its mount? Are there any mechanics that allow Centaurs to use more mundane mounts?

For Reference, the Centaur race in 5th Edition is located within Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica, pages 15 - 16.

Comment: Related: [Does the UA Centaur stack actually work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122712/does-the-ua-centaur-stack-actually-work), [Does a centaur PC also count as being mounted?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/150402/33569), [How do the rules work for a centaur being a mount?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/139366/33569), [Can a Centaur player character carry a Medium-sized creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/175996/33569)

Answer (score 11):

## Not unless the DM rules that the intended mount has "an appropriate anatomy"

The rules on [mounted combat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MountedCombat) state (emphasis mine):

> A willing creature that is at least one size larger than you and **that has an appropriate anatomy** can serve as a mount, using the following rules.

Now, finding a creature that's at least one size larger is pretty easy. The playable centaur race is size Medium, so any Large creature satisfies the first requirement. You might even find a willing one. But I think you would be hard-pressed to find a willing Large creature that has an "appropriate anatomy" to be ridden by a centaur.

---

Rules designer Jeremy Crawford unofficially addressed a semi-related question in a [May 2018 tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/996552478039552000) (though the question was about the [UA version of the centaur race](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA-Centaur.pdf) and [whether they could be stacked](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122712/does-the-ua-centaur-stack-actually-work)):

> *Doesn't that still mean that a centaur can ride another centaur?*
>
> **The rules on riding a mount specify that a mount must have a suitable size and anatomy for you to ride it (PH, 198). If the game makes an exception to part of that rule—about the creature's size, for instance—the other part of the rule still stands.**
>
> *But who or what determines suitable anatomy? Cuz the way I see it is that a centaur would have suitable anatomy for another centaur BECAUSE they're the same shape. Have you stacked up cups in a cabinet or something? They're still the same size but they stack very effectively.*
>
> **The DM decides.**

As referenced in the tweet, the Equine Build trait in the UA version of the trait had made an exception (as the tweet mentions) to the size requirement of the mount rules: "Finally, a Medium or smaller creature can ride on your equine back if you allow it." However, as Crawford states, even if the size requirement is overridden, the "appropriate anatomy" requirement is not.

This exception to the size requirement was removed from the trait in the published version of the [centaur](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/centaur) that appears in the *Guildmasters' Guide to Ravnica* (p. 16). Thus, no exception is made at all to the rules on mounts. Even if you find a creature of a suitable size (Large, or larger), it must still have a suitable anatomy to be mounted.

Comment: I like your answer solely based on "an appropriate anatomy" which can, in iteself, argue against Centaurs having next to no possible candidates, but only if this is how you interpret JC's answer. While this is indeed RAW, it is very vague, and one can only ASSUME RAI in this case, which can be argued that "an appropriate anatomy" was meant as anything quadrupedal with a solid enough build to carry someone/thing on it's back and traverse landscape at a reasonable pace. I feel this doesn't offer a very strong RAW solution based solely on this description of a mount. But, DM's call decideds all.

Comment: @BelynoldDayslayer: I think the rules on what counts as "appropriate anatomy" are intentionally left vague and up to DM discretion.

Comment: Fair assessment, and I don't disagree. I just like to find the most concrete and indisputable answers, but if that's the best answer we've got, it's the best we've got.

Comment: Aaaaand now I have an image of a large horse ridden by a medium centaur ridden by a small shetland pony...

Comment: Google Image gives you [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/8rsyyo/how_would_a_centaur_ride_another_centaur_oc_art/).